# (Closed) Leaflet.js GeoJson File: How I can get layer name on click event

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

This year I just have some adventure on Leaflet.JS mapping. I am newbie..

Since I am not familiar with Leaflet.JS with layer events I like to have some suggestion or solution whos have found it.

I have geojson direct to Leaflet like this

```
var geojsonFeatures =  {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "properties": {'name': 'TestLayer'},
      "features":[
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {'id': '01','popupContent': 'id=01'},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            175.2756,
            -37.7772
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {'id': '02','popupContent': 'id=02'},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                175.27364730834958,
                -37.77322501372662
              ],
              [
                175.27849674224854,
                -37.776617142149554
              ],
              [
                175.28351783752439,
                -37.784486280685925
              ],
              [
                175.28879642486572,
                -37.781365860467126
              ],
              [
                175.2824878692627,
                -37.7707486617024
              ],
              [
                175.27364730834958,
                -37.77322501372662
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]};
```

Then I load it as layer where can be edit to

```
//--load geojson file to maps--// 
L.geoJson(geojsonFeatures, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    });
```

Here, I like to get back GeoJson layer name if possible. I thought I can get from FeatureCollection under properties.name:-

```
var geojsonFeatures =  {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"properties": {'name': 'TestLayer'},
```

Inside onClick Event I try to get layer name back

```
//--- when click layer: get layer name, object id and json ----//
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {  //set each layer can be do editing
  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
  layer.on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.feature.properties.name);
    alert(drawnItems.getLayerId(layer));
  });
}
```

1. Result:  ***undefined*** on console.log for ..properties.name
2. Result:  random no like ***100*** on alert for ..getLayerId(layer)

But, I still can get layer name. I am stuck here. How to solve this problem?? I already 2 days think on this....

**Update 25/2/22**

After success get FeatureCollection properties data I move on @GrzegorzT. sample multi-layer-search. My main problem where I can remain this function:

```
...
.then(function (data) {
    // your name of layer
    // "properties": { "name": "TestLayer" },
    console.log(data.properties.name);

    let layer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.on("click", function (e) {
          alert(e.target);
        });
```

I still need layername and e.target value each time I click layer object(geometry).

Please help me everbody..

**Update 28/2/22**

I found few method regarding manipulate LeafletJS & GeoJson. Meanwhile bro @Grzegorz T. are really save my days. I closed this thread and open new thread regarding [Edit Selected Geometry Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71296996/leaflet-js-how-i-can-do-editing-geometry-on-specific-object-i-select-only) .

Comment: View the feature, layer and see if there is TestLayer there, if not, that is, maybe there is something wrong with json? ;). Then take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON and see how FeatureCollection is built. Use fetch and get this name and pass all date to L.geojson.

Comment: Hello @GrzegorzT. Thanks on advance for your reply. I am appreciate if you can give link or sample regarding this method "View the feature, layer and see if there is TestLayer there..".  I no idea how to run this method as you describe....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate geojson data file
And then using fetch or some other jquery ajax or axios get the data and add GeoJson to the map.

```js
fetch("geojsonFeatures.geojson")
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    // your name of layer
    // "properties": { "name": "TestLayer" },
    console.log(data.properties.name);

    let layer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.on("click", function (e) {
          alert(e.target);
        });
      },
    });
  });
```

**EDIT**

Full example [multi-layer-search](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#45.multi-layer-search)
Below is an example of how to add multiple files:

```js
["bar", "pharmacy", "restaurant"].map((json) => {
  fetchData(`./data/${json}.json`).then((data) => {
    L.geoJSON(data, geojsonOpts).addTo(poiLayers);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz T. for your reply. Let me try your suggestion and I will update for the result.

Comment: Hello @Grzegorz T.  <br> After I create geojson file separately and fetch in as your mention above, now I can get layer name when I click a layer object. <br> I would like to extend this functions and load 2 more layer. I also plan to do editing each layer I select later on. Maybe on new discussion/question and hope you can help me. Anyway Thanks you very much for your time and kindness.

Comment: Edited the example above and added a link to my entire example on how to add multiple layers.

Comment: Wow!! Amazing bro... I would explore example your given above and let U know the update.. Thanks you very much for your kindness and solutions.

Comment: Hello Grzegorz T. after I add multiple layer like your sample I am little bit confuse to remain `code` onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { `code`  and get result  `code` console.log(data.properties.name); `code` I am really lost where to place it inside your multi-layer-search sample.

Comment: I can see that you still like to create problems for yourself ;)
Insert `"properties": {'name': 'TestLayer'},`  into each "Feature" element - `"properties": {'id': '02', 'popupContent': 'id = 02', name: "TestLayer"}, `
This will solve all your problems.

Comment: Hahahaa... U are rights. But I need this and more prefer function onEachFeature(feature, layer) because I can get detail each target object I click. I also found I can get JSON string using this function too. That why I hope you have any idea to keep this function alive.

Comment: @nonothingnull for each popup pass the name of the file that you will pass the name from json https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/g3zufy0b/ I leave the analysis to you;)
Have fun ;)

Comment: Bro.. I just run your example and I am glad u keep function onEachFeature(feature, layer) as I need plus lot of hack u add on. Thanks you so much bro and u save my day!!. I will let u know the progress toward. Maybe after this I plan to try save geojson geometry to sqlite3 and reload back to leaflet. Maybe a new thread and will let u know and hope you can guide me regarding this matter.  Anyway thanks a lot for your brilliant idea and keep helping me.

Comment: Save geojson to indexedDB and Dexie.js can help you ;)