# (Closed) Leaflet.js: How I can Do Editing Geometry On Specific Object I Select Only?

Tags: javascript, python, sqlite, leaflet, geojson

I am very excited and lot of fun playing with Leaflet.JS on gis mapping stuff. I am newbie. I also very appreciate with bro @Grzegorz T. with the kindness and helping me on introduction me to Leaflet.JS.

Now, I am plan to do Editing geometry on specific object I select only. I already think how the flow and the result but the process???(hahahaa..). I also already know regarding DrawItems function on Leaflet.JS but I will use.

Let me describe simple flow before I do it...

A. I just using [jsfiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/g3zufy0b/) @Grzegorz T.

B. I add DrawItems

```
...
{ 'DrawLayer': drawnItems }, { position: 'topleft', collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
...

    //Add Draw Control//
    map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
        edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems,
            poly: {
                allowIntersection: false
            }
        },
        draw: {
            polygon: {
                allowIntersection: false,
                showArea: true
            }
        }
    }));

    //Draw Objects//
    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
        var layer = event.layer;
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });

    //Get Leaflet Object ID 
    drawnItems.on('click', function(event) {
      console.log("from drawnItems: " + event.layer._leaflet_id);
    });
        

  //Get Geometry from Layer & ID

  //Edit Only This Objects

  //Save This Editing Back to Original Layer & ID
```

on this part I saw a Problem is:

***1. I don't know how to copy original geometry I selected from layer to DrawLayer.***

***2. Hide only this geometry(id) on original layer until end of editing or cancel. (maybe change opacity to invisible)***

***3. After finish editing and while saving How I can save back to original layer and show the result to map.***

I hope whos hardcore and whos already found the easy way on Leaflet.JS can help me for this dirty work....

**Update 3/3/2022**

I found how to restyle the object(geometry) I selecting and this was cover for:
***2. Hide only this geometry(id) on original layer until end of editing or cancel. (maybe change opacity to invisible)***

Code like below:-

```
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {           
    //restyle the geom when display
    layer.setStyle({
      fillColor: "white",
      weight: 2,
      color: "#eb4034",
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
    });

    layer.on("mouseover", function (e) {
      // style
      this.setStyle({
        fillColor: "#eb4034",
        weight: 2,
        color: "#eb4034",
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
      });
    });
    layer.on("mouseout", function () {
      // style
      this.setStyle({
        fillColor: "#3388ff",
        weight: 2,
        color: "#3388ff",
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
      });
    });
    layer.on("click", function () {
      this.setStyle({
        fillColor: "transparent",
        weight: 0,
        color: "transparent",
        fillOpacity: 0,
      });

    });
  },
```

**Update 4/3/2022**

Anyone can help me how to passing geometry to drawnitems programmatically with editing mode? Let say I have whatever geometry like this below:-

......
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[16.3716,54.4414],[16.3946,54.4477],[16.4315,54.487],[16.4797,54.5164],[16.4968,54.5231],[16.5299,54.5407],[16.6145,54.5598],[16.6887,54.5696],[16.6991,54.5692],[16.7126,54.5542],[16.7392,54.5384],[16.7481,54.5276],[16.7392,54.5177],[16.7566,54.4946],[16.764,54.4861],[16.7933,54.4874],[16.8275,54.4648],[16.8211,54.4563],......
........
,"properties":{"id":4,"nazwa":"zachodniopomorskie"},"id":3}

How I can pass this polygon (geometry) into drawnItems layer programmatically?

Please help me and thanks you on advance for read this message.

Comment: After do some googling on internet and think on logic I found to re-color or re-style the object I selecting. Maybe after this I will found other things to finish this task. Code I found like above as update.

Comment: Hello, I have a problem regarding json data I mention above. This data from example @Grzegorz T.  I think just need the geometry type and coordinates. How I can get that by leaflet api or javascript/jquery only.

Comment: I also found a thousand vertex show up on editing mode of this object. How I can reduce this vertex being appear or some limit vertex show up each time mouse hover the object??

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a few days finally I found solutions to accomplish my task. It's not pretty but at least I fill ok and all I need are there.

I using

`layer.on("click", function(e) {`

to get the geometry and id from original layer. The original geometry I pass to drawnItems by using

```
geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(oriGeom);
geojsonLayer.getLayers()[0].addTo(drawnItems);
```

to draw back on drawing layer to do editing. On mean while I adjust the style on original geometry to invisible. The editable geometry only can see on this stage where user 'think' this is original geometry he/she do editing right now.

```
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {           
    //restyle the geom when display
    layer.setStyle({
      fillColor: "white",
      weight: 2,
      color: "#eb4034",
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
    });

    layer.on("mouseover", function (e) {
      // style
      this.setStyle({
        fillColor: "#eb4034",
        weight: 2,
        color: "#eb4034",
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
      });
    });
    layer.on("mouseout", function () {
      // style
      this.setStyle({
        fillColor: "#3388ff",
        weight: 2,
        color: "#3388ff",
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
      });
    });
    layer.on("click", function () {
      this.setStyle({
        fillColor: "transparent",
        weight: 0,
        color: "transparent",
        fillOpacity: 0,
      });
```

After finish the editing I save back to original layer by using Python class by search ID and replace the original coordinates to new coordinates (editGeom) only. :)

Then I delete all object inside drawnItems layer by this trick

```
  document.querySelector(".leaflet-draw-edit-remove").click(); //fake click Delete
  document.querySelector("ul li:last-child a").click(); //fake click Save All
```

That's all.